# Wilcoxon test on distribution derived from bootstrapping

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, wilcoxon-signed-rank

We have two Chocolate bags X and Y. Each chocolate bags have total 1000000 chocolate boxes randomly sampled from 100 types of chocolate boxes (B1, B2, …, B100). These chocolate boxes are of different sizes S1, S2, …, S100 having randomly filled with 10000 variety of chocolates V1, V2, .., V10000. I am interested in knowing whether there is a differential enrichment of certain chocolate variety in the two chocolate bags. Given that I have information about the number number of boxes and the chocolate varieties within them in each of the two bags, I calculated the fold enrichment of each chocolate variety in one bag over the other controlling for total number of chocolate in each bags. But this enrichment value is biased because I am also interested in finding chocolate varieties which are differentially enriched at the box levels between these bags (basically I don’t want the enrichment values to be influenced by few box types). So, I created the enrichment value distribution by bootstrapping the various box types from two bags multiple times (N=1000). Basically I want this distribution to be different from 1 (significantly enriched in one bag over the other). Given that I am bootstrapping only 1000 times, my power of this test is low and I am testing for 10000 chocolate varieties. My question is, can I perform wilcoxon one-sample test on the enrichment distribution generated by bootstrapping?